# setcookie() the cookies are always empty

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Not sure what i am doing wrong...

```
$articleid = "test";

$lastviewedarticles = array();

if (isset($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]) ) {
  $lastviewedarticles = unserialize($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]);
}

if (!in_array($articleid, $lastviewedarticles)){
    $count = count($lastviewedarticles);
    if($count>=29)
        array_shift($lastviewedarticles);
    $lastviewedarticles[] = $articleid;
}
setcookie('viewed_articles', serialize($lastviewedarticles), time()+60*60*24*30, '/', '.' . $domain);
```

Then this page reads the cookie and output the content:

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]) ) {
  $lastviewedarticles = unserialize($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]);
}
echo "cookie is currently:<br>";
print_r($lastviewedarticles);
```

As you can see on the test pages, the cookies are always empty

Comment: still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
... '.$domain');
    ^        ^
```

You use single quotes that means that php is not going to replace `$domain` with respective value from variable:

> [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):
>
> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and
>   escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
>   occur in single quoted strings.

And since you don't access to cookies from `.$domain` cookies are not set:

> [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):
>
> ***domain***
>
> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain
>   and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as
>   'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as
>   'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated »
>   RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Change it to:

```
... '.'.$domain);
```

Comment: Just updated the code... Still doesn't work :(  
setcookie('viewed_articles', serialize($lastviewedarticles), time()+60*60*24*30, '/', '.'.$domain);

Comment: @anarchOi Can you post what does `print_r` display? Can you use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: @anarchOi This means that cookies are set properly but value is not what you expect, check what `serialize($lastviewedarticles)` returns.

Comment: Check the code i posted, it is supposed to work. i printed $lastviewedarticles just before putting it in the cookie and it is not empty. Also if i use setcookie() without setting the domain name it will work. So it has something to do with setcookie() not being used propely. This will work = setcookie('viewed_articles', serialize($lastviewedarticles));

Comment: @anarchOi Take a look at your first sample. It always sets empty array in cookies (if there isn't a cookie, it is empty array, so `if` statement never executes, so in cookies empty array is set. If there's a cookie (which is empty, because you've set so in previous run) it reassigns `$lastviewedarticles` empty array). :)

Comment: not sure if i understand what you mean... could you edit the part of the code that isn't working ?

Answer (score 0):

As of [RFC 2109](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109.html), the `domain` parameter has to be set with a starting dot (see http://php.net/setcookie). Please try that, your code seems to be okay. And please remove the single-quotes from `'.$domain.'`.

Comment: Really? So I'm sorry - have not noticed that.

Comment: Yes: `Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.`

Comment: Yep, you're right. at ietf.org it's marked as historic. My fault - sorry.